# Angular ng-init like for VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Im using **vuejs** and some time i need to create new variables in the template.

In angular I could go:

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="myText='Hello World!'">
<h1>{{myText}}</h1>
```

How can that be achived in **vuejs**?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please define WHY you need `ng-init` alternative? Maybe you just need to pass data from the server to the vue component

Comment: @MaxLyashuk some time you have very complex variables. somehing like `feed[entity.UserName][symbol[0]].Data` it is very ugly and un readable to work like that.

Answer (score 6):

It's not really recommended to init from the template, but it is possible to do this with a directive:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
});
```

Which you can use like:

```
<div v-init:myvar="'foo'"></div>
```

All that does is take the `binding argument` (this bit after the `:`) and sets it's value the the `binding value` on the Vue instance's data property.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/snpLtt8c/

A couple of caveats for that though, firstly `binding.arg` is always passed as lower case, so if you want to use camelCase variables you will probably need to implement something that converts kebab-case to camelCase:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {

    // convert kebab-case to camelCase
    let arg = binding.arg.split('-').map((arg, index) => {
      return (index > 0) ? arg[0].toUpperCase() + arg.substring(1) : arg;
    }).join('');

    vnode.context[arg] = binding.value;
  }
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div v-init:my-text="'Hello World'"></div>
```

Here's the Fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/craig_h_411/9xepfpw3/

Secondly, you still need to declare your variables upfront in `data`.

Comment: It's ok for one single variable, but it does not work in loops for example : http://jsfiddle.net/k9j7murd/

Comment: Does not work in version 3 :/

Answer (score 2):

For the ones that wanted the same functionality but instead of initializing a data property, it calls a function/method on your Vue instance which may, in turn, assign values or call an API, check this out.

**v-init directive**

```js
Vue.directive('init', {
    bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
        vnode.context[binding.expression]();
    }
});
```

**Sample Vue instance**

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#some-element',
    methods: {
        callApi: function () {
            // add your http api call here --.
       }
    }
});
```

**Usage in Html**

```html
<div id="some-element" v-init="callApi"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The slightly hacky-looking but perfectly valid way to get that effect is with a `v-for`:

```
<div v-for="myText in ['Hello World!']">
<h1>{{myText}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for my usecase in replicating `ng-init`. This directive `eval`s the `binding.value` to the expected value:

```
Vue.directive('init', {
    bind: function(el, binding /*, vnode*/) {
        console.log(binding.value); //# This line is optional, of course.
    }
});
```

e.g.:

```
<div v-init="somevar = 'someval'"></div>
```

With thanks to @craig_h as his code was the basis of this

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this by adding a script tag in the HTML code of the page (outside the app div).

```
<script>
    var somevar = "somevalue";

    // or
    var someobj = {somekey1: "some value 1", somekey2: "some value 2};
</script>
```

Then in the "mounted" callback of the Vue app:

```
mounted() {
    this.somevar = window.somevar;

    // or:
    this.someobj = Vue.util.extend(this.someobj , window.someobj);

    // etc, you get the idea
}
```